# Cannot declare variable 'ML' to be of abstract type 'MyList<int>' when using template with virtual functions

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions

Good night.
I'm implementing an assignment in C++ contains templates and virtual functions, so when I call the parameterized constructor it gives me that error "Cannot declare variable 'ML' to be of abstract type 'MyList'"

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class MyList
{
protected:
    int arraySize;
    T *arr;
public:
    MyList<T>(){}
    MyList<T>(int arraySize)
    {
        this->arraySize = arraySize;
        this->arr = new T[arraySize];
    }
    int getSize()
    {
        return this->arraySize;
    }
    //virtual void addElem() = 0;
    virtual int getElem() = 0;
    //virtual bool isEmpty() = 0;
    ///virtual bool isFull() = 0;
    ///virtual void clearItems() = 0;
    ~MyList()
    {
        delete [] this->arr;
    }
};

template <typename C>
class MyStack : public MyList<C>
{
public:
    int getElem()
    {
        return 2;
    }
};
int main()
{
    MyStack <int> MS;
    MyList <int> ML(5);
    MS.getElem();
}
```

Sorry for implementing the source code, main and headers in one file, but it's required for the assignment delivery.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have an abstract class with pure virtual functions. Such a class cannot be instantiated (that's what it means to be abstract) - it needs to be derived from, and those pure virtual functions need to be overridden in that derived class. The fact that `MyList<int>` is a template instantiation is irrelevant.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

That is what the error says. You can not make an object of an abstract class. Which is a class having at least one pure virtual function. You can however instantiate `MyStack` as it provides a definition for the pure virtual function `getElem` of the parent class `MyList`.

Comment: Okay i got you, but in the Assignment Instructions I should make a parameterized constructor which define the Array_Size in MyList which is the abstract class, so how could I determine the array size?

Comment: @MohamedWael Why would you need getElem to be virtual?

Comment: Unfortunately it's the collage assignment's instructions
all the functions except getSize() are pure virtual.

Comment: The instructions:
The pure virtual functions:
- addElem which adds an element
- getElem which returns an element, after removing it from the array.
- isEmpty which returns true if the array is empty
- isFull()which returns true if the array is full
- clearItems() which empties the array;

Comment: You can't have pure virtual function and making objects of that class at the same time anyway

Answer (score 1):

Simply get rid of `ML`, you are not using it anyway. Add an `int` constructor to `MyStack` that calls the `int` constructor of `myList`

```cpp
template <typename C>
class MyStack : public MyList<C>
{
public:
    MyStack(int arraySize) : MyList<C>(arraySize){} // <- add this

    int getElem()
    {
        return 2;
    }
};
```

And then you can use it like this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    MyStack <int> MS(5);
    MS.getElem();
}
```

Also, on a side note, `MyList` is not compliant with the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), as it lacks a copy constructor and a copy assignment operator. And its default constructor is not initializing the class members at all.